# Is there a way to find all apps in Nova Launcher which are NOT in folders (similar to Folder Organizer)?

Tags: app-drawer, home-screen-folders, nova-launcher, folder-organizer

I am contemplating getting a Nova Prime launcher, as opposed to my current combination of Nova free and Folder Organizer.

The main feature of Folder Organizer that I see as a must-have and not sure if possible on Nova is an easy way to find ALL of your installed un-labeled apps (via "Other Applications automatic label") so you can work on relabeling/foldering them <sub>(assuming your goal is to have a proper folder for every app you have)</sub>.

**Is there such a feature (easily find all not-in-folders installed apps) in Nova Prime?**

If not, a second subquestion is, is there a good replacement launcher among those well known (Apex, GO, etc...) that has such a feature?

Comment: I think Folder Organizer organizes apps (and others) in a way that most (if not all) launchers do not. I have Nova Prime, and it's a very good investment. I do not see why you can't have both Nova Prime and Folder Organizer.

Comment: @geffchang - mostly, resource concerns. I'm too used to my old too-slow DX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you have a way of (by default) forcing Nova to remove any apps that are in a folder from its main app drawer.

As such, you can use the main app drawer configured this way to get a list of non-foldered apps.